# Node.js - user Authentication with Passport (Learn Node.js by building 10 projects course)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm following a tutorial which probably is outdated in some moments, but anyway I would like to finish it.
Here is the problem - I stacked on user Authentication with Passport and can't Login into my website though there are no mistakes in my code and even in console (what is the most terrible part cuz I can't see what actually is wrong). After clicking button "submit" it must redirect me to members area page but it simply doesn't respond. And no errors on console, like everything is working fine! I'm sorry if I did or said something wrong, it's my first question here :) And thank you for any help or advice! Here are my code snippets:

```
    // In app.js:

    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var uploads = multer({dest: './uploads'});
    var flash = require('connect-flash');
    var mongo = require('mongodb');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var db = mongoose.connection;


    var routes = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');

    var app = express();

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');


    // Handle file uploads
    var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    // Handle Express Sessions
    app.use(session({
        secret:'secret',
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true
    }));

    // passport
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    // Validator
    app.use(expressValidator({
      errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
          var namespace = param.split('.')
          , root    = namespace.shift()
          , formParam = root;

        while(namespace.length) {
          formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
        }
        return {
          param : formParam,
          msg   : msg,
          value : value
        };
      }
    }));

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


    app.use(flash());
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
      next();
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
        res.locals.user = req.user || null;
        next();
    });

    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);


    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->






    // In users.js in routes:

    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var User = require('../models/user');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var uploads = multer({dest: './uploads'});
    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.send('respond with a resource');
    });

    router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('register', {
          'title': 'Register'
      });
    });

    router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('login', {
          'title': 'Login'
      });
    });

    router.post('/register', uploads.single('profileimage'), function(req, res, next) {
        var name = req.body.name;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var password2 =  req.body.password2;


        // Check for Image Field
        if (req.file) {
            console.log('uploading File...');

            // File Info
            var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
            var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;

            var profileImageMime = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
            var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
            var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extension;
            var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
        } else {
            // Set a Default Image
            var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
        }

        // Form Validation

        req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email','Email not valid').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('username','Username field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password2','Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

        // Check for errors
        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
            res.render('register', {
                errors: errors,
                name: name,
                email: email,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                password2: password2
            });
        } else {
            var newUser = new User({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                username: username,
                password: password,
                profileImage: profileImageName
            });

                // Create User
                User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
                    if(err)throw err;
                    console.log(user);
                });

                //Success Message
                req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may log in');

                res.location('/');
                res.redirect('/');
        }
    });

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done){
            User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(!user){
                    console.log('Unknown User');
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
                }

                User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(isMatch){
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    ));

    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect: '/users/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res){
        console.log('Authentication Successful');
        req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        req.flash('success', 'You have logged out');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    });

    module.exports = router;




  res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });

    module.exports = app;


<!-- end snippet -->



    // In package.json:

    {
      "name": "nodeauth",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
        "debug": "~2.2.0",
        "express": "~4.13.4",
        "jade": "~1.11.0",
        "morgan": "~1.7.0",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
        "mongodb":"*",
        "mongoose":"*",
        "connect-flash":"*",
        "express-validator":"*",
        "express-session":"*",
        "express-messages":"*",
        "passport":"*",
        "passport-local":"*",
        "passport-http":"*",
        "multer":"*"
      }
    }






    // In user.js in models:

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    // User Schema
    var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            index: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            bcrypt: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        profileimage: {
            type: String
        }

    });

    var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

    module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassowrd, hash, callback){
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassowrd, hash, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, isMatch);
        });
    }

    module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
        User.findById(id, callback);
    }

    module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
        var query = {username: username};
        User.findOne(query, callback);
    }

    module.exports.createUser = function(newUser,callback){
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
            if(err) throw err;

            // Set Hashed password
            newUser.password = hash;

            // Create User
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Did you try adding a successRedirect to your passport.authenticate?

Comment: router.post('/login', passport.authenticate(('local',{failureRedirect: '/users/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), {successRedirect: '/users/login', successFlash: 'It worked!'}), function(req, res){

Comment: I'm sorry, did you mean it this way? This makes mistake and as I can understand whole block works kinda like "if statement" so in case of success we have this line:  req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');

Comment: Anyway, the problem is - it simply doesn't respond even if I'm trying to login with unregistered user (like typing fake username and password)

Comment: Actually the successRedirect is a member of the same object as the failureRedirect. See here: http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate. Sorry if this isn't helpful, this is a tough issue to debug without being in front of it.

Comment: Check if the submit button in jade view file has any eventHandler attached to it to send the form details for authentication

Comment: @jjwilly16 Yeah, I understand, but I'm still trying... Thanks a lot, anyway!

Comment: @DiwakarMoturu I've checked it, everything seems to be fine in my login.jade file

Comment: @EugeMorrow, Even I did the project from the same course in July and everything worked well for me. Try to use chrome Dev Console to check exactly whats happening during the click event of submit button and console log the stuff thats reaching the specified route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue.  The problem is the form.  Remove the enctype part and it works!

Edit: The reason why removing the enctype caused it to work is because then it does not need Multer.  Multer's API changed since this was recorded.  You need to include uploads.single('profileimage') as the second param in the post.

Please remember to define the require for multer in the new way as well.

Example:

```
var multer = require('multer');
// To handle the inclusion of the extension in the filename
var path = require('path')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/images/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)) //Appending extension
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

The above example was taken from the next project in the course that required an upload of an image.  It was only when hitting this project that I was able to find the required workaround to make it work as its supposed it.  Reading the documentation on multer helped as well.